# Repeating headings in for-loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I have `df`:

```
          id    timestamp               data    Date
27001   27242   2020-01-01 09:07:21.277 19.5    2020-01-01
27002   27243   2020-01-01 09:07:21.377 19.0    2020-01-01
27581   27822   2020-01-02 07:53:05.173 19.5    2020-01-02
```

and a for-loop generating graphs in batch and a table at the end:

```
for date in df['Date'].unique():   
  df_date = df[df['Date'] == date]

  ...

  number = []
  ax.autoscale()    
  plt.title(date)

  number.append([date, np.count_nonzero(df2['events'][minLim:maxLim]) ])      

  df_number=pd.DataFrame(number,columns=['Date', 'Count'])

  display(df_number)
```

I want to get the output in a table but the heading is repeating itself:
[image]

If I change the indentation of the last two rows:

```
for date in df['Date'].unique():   
  df_date = df[df['Date'] == date]

  ...

  number = []
  ax.autoscale()    
  plt.title(date)

  number.append([date, np.count_nonzero(df2['events'][minLim:maxLim]) ])      

df_number=pd.DataFrame(number,columns=['Date', 'Count'])

display(df_number)
```

it will return only the last row of the table:

[image]

How can I remove the repeating headings but leave the top one and replace the indexes, starting from 1? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a new dataframe each iteration, try to append them all together and display once at the end:

```py
# Initialize df_number
df_number = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Count'])

for date in df['Date'].unique():   
  df_date = df[df['Date'] == date]

  ...

  number = []
  ax.autoscale()    
  plt.title(date)

  number.append([date, np.count_nonzero(df2['events'][minLim:maxLim]) ])      

  # Append the new data
  df_number=df_number.append(pd.DataFrame(number, columns=['Date', 'Count']))

# Display once
display(df_number)
```

Comment: Hi FBruzessi, the first time I ran the code it returned a table with wrong column orders but the headings were no longer repeating themselves. When I ran again it returned `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`.